# Android, trying to figure out how to remove a button

Tags: android, view

I'm dymcally adding EditView, and would like to remove them from a LinearLayout container,
the code I use to add the edit views

```
// month
mMonth[index] = new EditText(this);
result = cDates.GetStrMonth(index).toCharArray();
mMonth[index].setText(result,0,result.length);
layout.addView(mMonth[index])
```

Ted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
layout.removeView(mMonth[index]);
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove all the children you could simply

```
ArrayList<View> views = layout.getTouchables();
                for(View v1: views){
                    layout.removeView(v1);
                }
```

if you need to be more careful about what view you remove, you will need to inspect each view v1 to determine if you want to remove it or not.